# All members of class in IronPython

Tags: c#, ironpython

I'm currently writing a scripting system for a game, where I want to define a base class in C# which can be derived from in Python. However after executing the script I want to get access to the dynamically added member variables in the Python class (names, types and values). Thus I want to to be able to create savegames (by storing the values of all variables). Here's (one) attempt I've made:

```
Engine = Python.CreateEngine();
Scope = Engine.CreateScope();
ScriptSource scriptSource = Engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(@"from MyEngine import Foo

class Foo2(Foo):
    newProp = 'This is a property'    # This should be added to _dynamicMembers
");

scriptSource.Execute(Scope);
dynamic foo2 = Scope.GetVariable("Foo2");
dynamic foo2_instance = foo2();    // 'newProp' is visible in the debugger....
dynamic foo2_instance_props = foo2_instance._dynamicMembers;    // ...but somehow not added to _dynamicMembers
```

where The base class `Foo` is similar to the one in [this blog post](https://dontcodetired.com/blog/post/Creating-Your-Own-Custom-Dynamic-C-Classes):

```
public class Foo : DynamicObject
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> _dynamicMembers = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public Foo()
    {}

    // These Try*Member methods are never called from 'Foo2'
    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result) 
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("TryGetMember");
        return _dynamicMembers.TryGetValue(binder.Name, out result);
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("TrySetMember");
        if (_dynamicMembers.ContainsKey(binder.Name))
        {
            _dynamicMembers[binder.Name] = value;
            return true;
        }

        return base.TrySetMember(binder, value);
    }

    public override bool TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, object[] args,
    out object result)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("TryInvokeMember");
        return base.TryInvokeMember(binder, args, out result);
    }
}
```

But as indicated in the commets abvove the new variable `newProp` is not added, neither are the methods `TryGetMember`, `TrySetMember` or `TryInvokeMember` called. I've tried many more approaches like accessing the meta object:

```
SourceUnit sourceUnit = HostingHelpers.GetSourceUnit(scriptSource)
Parser parser = Parser.CreateParser(new CompilerContext(sourceUnit, Engine.GetCompilerOptions(), ErrorSink.Default),(PythonOptions)LangContext.Options);
PythonAst ast = parser.ParseFile(false);
dynamic memNames = foo2.GetMetaObject(ast).GetDynamicMemberNames(); //Works but contains all kinds of methods from subclasses + how do I get values and types now?
```

or using C# reflection:

```
foreach (var property in foo2.GetType().GetProperties()) // Doesn't return the member variables
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Name = " + property.Name + ", Type = " + property.PropertyType);
    Debug.WriteLine("Attr = " + property.Attributes);
}
```

So my question: How can I achieve the goal described in the first paragraph? Also I would like to directly access a list **for the static member variables** of the Python class (i.e. `foo2.newProp` rather than `foo2_instance.newProp`), so I don't want to create an instance of `Foo2` to access `_dynamicMembers`.
Many thanks in advance!